# How does reduction of a decision problem work?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, decision-problem

I am given the following problem description:

> Given $l$ lists, $L_1$, $L_2$, . . .$L_l$ each containing $N$ bit vectors of $n$ bits each, we want to find tuples $(x_1,···,x_l)$ with $x_i$ in the corresponding $L_i$, such that:$$⊕_{i=1}^l x_i = S $$ for some target n-bit vector $S$.  In other words, we want to find one element from list such that the XOR of the chosen elements is the target $S$

Now I am required to show that if we can solve the equation in the case where $S=0$, we can for the same cost solve it for an arbitrary value (with exact same parameters, $N$, $n$, and $l$).  I am given a hint to proceed by **reducing** an instance with $S \neq 0$ to an instance with $S=0$.

What am I missing that I am not able to reduce it?

Answer (score 3):

Let $I$ be your instance and consider the instance $I'$ obtained by replacing each bit vector $y$ in $L_1$ with $y' = y \oplus S$ (where $\oplus$ denotes bitwise xor). Call $L'_1$ the list containing all vectors $y'$.

Consider the tuples $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_l)$ and $(x'_1, x_2, \dots, x_l)$ where $x_i \in L_i$ and $x'_1 \in L'_1$.
We have:
$$
      x_1 \oplus ( \oplus_{i=2}^l x_i ) = \oplus_{i=1}^l x_i  = S \iff  (x_1 \oplus S) \oplus  ( \oplus_{i=2}^l x_i ) = x'_1\oplus  ( \oplus_{i=2}^l x_i ) = S \oplus S = 0,
$$
showing that there is a solution to $I$ iff there is a solution to $I'$ (and you can convert one solution into the other in linear time).

Comment: But doesn't the question ask for 'same cost'? As in, your solution would require polynomial time in conversion if I get it right.

Comment: It's not clear to me what "same cost" means, since you never define "cost". Notice that the reduction in the answer requires at most **linear** time and that any algorithm that solves any of the two problems must require at least linear time in the worst case (since this is the time requite to read the whole input). It follows that there is no asymptotic difference between the *time complexities* of the two problems.